# Share Array of UIImages With Text via UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, share, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using **UIActivityViewController** to share **text** and **images** both in Swift using the following code:

```
@IBAction func shareTapped(_ sender: Any) {

   var text = "I am enjoying swift"
   var image = UIImage(systemName: "person")

   let itemsToShare = [text, image!]
   let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 

   self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This works fine when I share it with **Skype** but when I try to share it with **WhatsApp**, it only shares text.

There are **two questions** now:

1. Can I share both image and text on WhatsApp or iOS does not support this?
2. Can I share the array of images along with text? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, currently there is no way to share both image and text together on `WhatsApp`.
However, you can post one at a time. It is a limitation of WhatsApp under iOS, it is nothing related to `UIActivityViewController`.

> [image]

For more read from [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715)